# How can I upload image to imgur using VPN?

Tags: c#, image-uploading, vpn, imgur

In my county -Turkey- to upload and see images in Imgur is forbidden. When I tried to upload image with my client-id it throws a 403 Forbidden error. So I think the solution is upload using VPN. But I don't know how. I tried it as below

```
        using (var w = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection
            {
                {"image", Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(path))}
            };
            WebProxy pr = new WebProxy("euro217.vpnbook.com");
            pr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("vpnbook", "caPhahu4");
            pr.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            pr.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            w.Proxy = pr;
            w.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clid);
            byte[] response = w.UploadValues("https://api.imgur.com/3/upload.xml", values);

            Console.WriteLine(XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(response)));
            //now process response as you'd like. the link is encapsulated by <link></link> in the response.
        }
```

I have found the VPN adress and credential infos from a public site. I think the informations is not wrong. But not sure.Please help!.

EDIT: I have solved the problem. The problem is I got the clientID from developer.google.com for OAuth API. I thought I was right,but I was wrong. The id must be taken from https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient. This solved the issue. Thanks everyone tried to help.

Comment: You say you use a VPN, but you are using a proxy. That is not the same.

Comment: I got this code from a topic in this site as a result of my search about VPN and to be honest, I have not much information about VPN or proxy. Sorry about that. But my main goal is to upload image to Imgur which is a forbidden site. I don't know which one will be used, VPN or Proxy.

Comment: If you just want to upload using vpn, [see these instructions](http://www.vpnbook.com/howto/setup-pptp-vpn-on-windows7) how to make the vpn connection in windows 7. After you have created the vpn connection, you can upload normally. If you do want to use a proxy, see for example [this list](http://www.publicproxyservers.com/proxy/list1.html), but a proxy has limitations. A vpn is probably better.